# What does it mean to say something in philosophy "goes back to" something else?

Tags: epistemology

For example, "this goes back to Kant, which goes back to Plato."

Comment: Is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to share a little more about the context and motivations of the concern? (What have you been reading that might have made this an interesting or important question for you? What have you found out so far?)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it means that an antecedent philosopher has given a well-known discussion of that topic.